# ServiceStack ORMLite not deserializing JSON stored in DB text field

Tags: json, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-text

I have some telemetry data that was stored in a text field as JSON.  I'm attempting to reverse-engineer POCOs to seamlessly extract and present that data without having to do any post-processing ForEach loops.

When I attempt to manually parse the JSON string in the data field, it works.  When I am selecting via ORMLite, it comes back with the default object.  What am I missing?

**Works**

```
string x = "{\"alive\":true,\"paperStatus\":\"0:NoIssue\"}";
var telemetry = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<KioskTelemetryData>(x);
```

**Doesn't populate Data field**

```
var exp = Db.From<KioskTelemetryLog>()
                    .Where(q => q.Identifier == request.Identifier)
                    .OrderByDescending(q => q.Timestamp);

var data = Db.Select(exp);
```

Here is what the data records look like:

```
Id  Identifier  IsCurrent   RedemptionCenterId  Timestamp               Status  Data
1   XXX        0            NULL                2015-11-24 11:10:53.527 1       {"alive":true,"paperStatus":"1:LowPaper"}
2   XXX        0            NULL                2015-12-01 12:16:56.653 0       {"alive":true,"paperStatus":"0:NoIssue"}    
1   XXX        1            NULL                2015-12-01 18:32:11.337 2       {"alive":false}
```

And here are the POCOs:

```
[Alias("TelemetryLog")]
public class KioskTelemetryLog
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }

    public int? RedemptionCenterId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    // 0 = okay, 1 = warning, 2 = error
    public sbyte Status { get; set; }

    public KioskTelemetryData Data { get; set; }
}

public class KioskTelemetryData
{
    public bool Alive { get; set; }
    public string PaperStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default complex type serializer for OrmLite is the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format) (except for PostgreSQL which uses JSON). OrmLite does support [pluggable text serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pluggable-complex-type-serializers), e.g. you can change SQL Server to use JSON for serializing complex types with:

```
SqlServerDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonStringSerializer();
```

If it's not serializing correctly it's like a serialization error, you can try [enable logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging) for more info about the error, e.g:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new ConsoleLogFactory(debugEnabled:true);
```

Comment: Ung - totally missed that in the [docs here] (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pluggable-complex-type-serializers).  Is it possible to override the behavior on a query basis like you can with the JsonSerializer?

Comment: @jklemmack no, you could temporarily override it and revert it in a finally statement but that's not threadsafe. Another approach is to declare the property as a string then have a method like `KioskTelemetryData GetData()` which returns the deserialized version.

Comment: Ah - I really like the extra method approach to do the deserialization, since the same telemetry table holds data for several different categories of devices.  And I'd probably implement it as read-only properties based on the type.  That lets me re-translate the whole POCO to JSON and feed it to the dashboard website.