# ServiceStack OrmLite: JSON fild deserialization Issue

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a table in MySql:

```
CREATE TABLE db.catalog (
    id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    pictures json DEFAULT NULL
)
```

and declaration form code

```
public class catalog {        
   public string id { get; set; }
   public List<string> pictures { get; set; }
}
```

and I have data: **pictures = ["JavaScript", "ES2015", "JSON"]**

[image]

When you run the query through OrmLite deserializing is not correct...

It is evident that the deserialization as in the cases of key-value data.

I'm doing something wrong? or is it meant to be?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help, the question is closed:

```
MySqlDialect.Provider.StringSerializer = new JsonDataContractSerializer();
```

Thanks @mythz: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35186935/7015077